# SQL cast issue near the from statement

Tags: sql, case, inner-join

I am trying to cast the row status while displaying the value in the grid view , but i am getting error near the from string . Kindly guide

```
select
    a.Budget_id as ID,
    b.User_Name as Created_By,
    a.Created_datetime as created_date,
    a.Row_Status as Auth_Status,
    a.AuthRemarks as Remarks,
    case 
        when a.Row_Status = 'P' then 'Yet To Be Authorised' 
        when a.Row_Status = 'D' then 'Authorization Declined'
from 
    budget_master a
join 
    TBL_USERS b on a.Created_by = b.User_Id
```

I am beginner please guide

Answer (score 3):

`case` needs `end`. Aliasing the column may also be a good idea. Finally, meaningful table aliases make for more readable code:

```
select
    bm.Budget_id as ID,
    u.User_Name as Created_By,
    bm.Created_datetime as created_date,
    bm.Row_Status as Auth_Status,
    bm.AuthRemarks as Remarks,
   case 
       when bm.Row_Status = 'P' then 'Yet To Be Authorised' 
       when bm.Row_Status = 'D' then 'Authorization Declined'
   end as status  --> here
from budget_master bm
join TBL_USERS u on bm.Created_by = u.User_Id
```